# How to encrypt data in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to encrypt data using Python?
Like if data is `Hello, I am a coder!`
and if the password is `123AAVVC`
then how to encrypt `Hello, I am a coder` into unreadable characters like `0000 0000 0101 0101`
and only be decrypted to `Hello, I am a coder` if it has the password that is `"123AAVVC"`.

Here is my Code:

```
def InputPassword():
    Msg = "Enter your password: "
    InputPassword = input(Msg)
    return InputPassword

def InputData():
    Msg = "Enter your data: "
    InputData = input(Msg)
    return InputData


def Encode():
    Psd = InputPassword()
    Data = InputData()
    LenPsd = len(Psd)
    if LenPsd >= 8: #This will allow user to enter password that has 8 or more character
        if Psd:
            pass
            #Rest of the code, I know till here.
        else:
            print("Error!")
    else:
        print("Passord is too short!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        Encode()
    except:
        pass
```

Please help me with to code this prgram, I am new to Python Programming
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I think your question is answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815656/simple-encrypt-decrypt-lib-in-python-with-private-key Regards,
Y

Comment: It seems like ``# Rest of the code`` is actually *all* of the code for this issue. Have you tried anything so far? Did you look for encryption algorithms (*encoding* means something else than what you described) that you can use? Are you looking for specific features of the encryption, e.g. speed of encryption or difficulty of decryption?

Comment: I looking for a way how to encrypt data with a password and that encrypted data to be decrypted by entering the password. Like using replace() funtion to replace "hello" to "0001 0010 1010", so "0001 0010 1010" is a key (password) to decrypt this "0001 0010 1010" to "hello".

Comment: Well, there are *lots* of ways to encrypt data. What is your criteria for a suitable encryption algorithm? The "encrypted data" ``0000 0000 0101 0101`` is just a made-up result, not an actually desired result, yes?

Comment: AES is a suitable encryption algorithm I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want encryption, since you are using a password.

You can use something simple as pycryptodome, to make unbreakable ciphers:

```
def __EncryptionBase(text, password):
    iv = get_random_bytes(16)
    cipher = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=IV)
    padded_data = pad(text.encode(), cipher.block_size)
    ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(padded_data)
    return IV + ciphertext

def __DecryptionBase(text, password, IV):
    cipher = AES.new(password, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=IV)
    paddedBytes = cipher.decrypt(text)
    originalBytes = unpad(paddedBytes, cipher.block_size)
    return originalBytes
```

If you need further simplification of the above code, post a comment

---

As per request a cipher without any package and few line of code.
pretty much the most simple encryption out there , Here you go ;D

```
state = [None] * 256
p = q = None


def setKey(key):
    global p, q, state
    key = [ord(c) for c in key]
    state = [n for n in range(256)]
    p = q = j = 0
    for i in range(256):
        if len(key) > 0:
            j = (j + state[i] + key[i % len(key)]) % 256
        else:
            j = (j + state[i]) % 256
        state[i], state[j] = state[j], state[i]


def byteGenerator():
    global p, q, state
    p = (p + 1) % 256
    q = (q + state[p]) % 256
    state[p], state[q] = state[q], state[p]
    return state[(state[p] + state[q]) % 256]


def encrypt(inputString, password):
    setKey(password)

    a = [ord(p) ^ byteGenerator() for p in inputString]
    b = ""
    for i in a:
        b += str(i) + ","
    b = b[:-1]
    return b


def decrypt(YourCipheredNumericList, password):
    setKey(password)
    a = YourCipheredNumericList.split(",")
    if a[-1] == "":
        a.pop()
    b = []
    for i in a:
        b.append(int(i))
    return "".join([chr(c ^ byteGenerator()) for c in b])

a = encrypt("hello world", "123")
print(a)
b = decrypt(a, "123")
print(b)
```

Here's a challenge for you...
Using the simple encryption above i created two hidden messages to you, try and break them and tell me my secrets :D

Easy to break (Takes me less than 2 minute):

```
MyFirstSecretMessage = decrypt("66,28,211,12,44,178,181,41,254,43,244,148,110,52,56,175", *MySecretPassword*)
```

Very hard (I personally cannot break this message)

```
MySecondSecretMessage = decrypt("129,189,215,167,37,158,208,75,4,161,96,213", *MySecretPassword*)
```

Comment: Is there a way to encrypt data without using any Python package?

Comment: Yes it is. But inventing a new kind of encryption or implementing an existing one isn't as easy as it seems. Why not take an existing solution?

Comment: @Mr.LegalHacker i can post my own version of encryption that only uses code a little later, it sucks in term of unbreakability... but i can 100% tell you nor you or anyone in you skill set wont be able to break it :D

Comment: @Mr.LegalHacker There you go, try to break my hidden messages and tell what they say :D